# Default password for new Cluster in MongoDB Atlas

Tags: python, mongodb

What is the default password in a new cluster in MongoDB Atlas? I'm trying with `pass` `password` `admin` `root`

```
mongodb+srv://root:<password>@cluster.mongodb.net/blablabla
```

when running my python code shows the error

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth Authentication failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB Atlas does not have a default user/password combination.

To enable access to a cluster you need to:

- [Add a new database user](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/) with appropriate permissions
- [Configure whitelist entries](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/) to allow remote access to your cluster from trusted IP(s)

See [Get Started with Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/getting-started/) for a full list of steps including screenshots.